# Преобразовать текст в изображение (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста по такому моменту.
Получаю из БД строку, и мне нужно наложить её поверх готового изображения.
Одно изображение планирую накладывать поверх другого при помощи [этой библиотеки](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction). Но как строку, которая пришла из БД перевести в картинку?

Answer (score 1):

Как обычно, сутки мучался, написал вопрос, через 20 минут решил.
через ту же самую библиотеку:

```html
 $img->text($coupone, 315, 745, function($font) {

                $font->file(public_path('/arial.ttf'));

                $font->size(28);

                $font->color('#000');

                $font->align('center');

                $font->valign('bottom');

            });
```